# Clicking on html "select" element using Safari on iPhone, causes the native mobile keyboard to hide the element

Tags: html, select, scroll, safari

Clicking on html "select" element will cause the native mobile keyboard to slide into view which hides the focused "select" element. 
however, this problem can not be reproduced when clicking on "input" element:
The native mobile keyboard to slides into view, while the view is being scrolled up, so the focused "input" field is not hidden.

you can watch this behaviour on this codepen using safari on iPhone:

[codpen](http://codepen.io/segevassaf/pen/aZBLrz)

```
<div style='padding: 100px'>
  <select>
    <option value="aaa">aaa</option>
    <option value="bbb">bbb</option>
    <option value="ccc">ccc</option>
  </select>
  <input type='email'></input>
</div>
```

I used hidden input field to overcome this issue, but it is too hacky. any other suggestions?

Comment: Question is unclear, please consider rewording.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I rephrase it a bit, I hope it is more clear now.